# Twitter Streaming API filter - Filter By Location Getting an error - For filter by work works correctly

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using the Twitter API to get the streaming data

```
for tweet in api.GetStreamFilter(locations=-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8):
    print (tweet)
    break
```

and I am getting an error message when I try to filter by locations

```
File "<ipython-input-28-51193e42f674>", line 2
    for tweet in api.GetStreamFilter(locations=-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8):
                                                      ^
***SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument***
```

If I use the filter for a word

```
for tweet in api.GetStreamFilter(track = 'Facebook'):
    print (tweet)
    break
```

It works correctly.

When I use location then I am getting the error.

I am following the

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters

and it says location

```
Parameter value             Tracks Tweets from...
-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8   San Francisco
-74,40,-73,41               New York City
-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8,-74,40,-73,41 
                            San FranciscoOR New York City
```

### Update

I am getting the below error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vSQn.jpg)

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-bd71c23fee89> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 for tweet in api.GetStreamFilter(locations=(-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8)):
      3     print (tweet)
      4     break

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twitter\api.py in GetStreamFilter(self, follow, track, locations, languages, delimited, stall_warnings, filter_level)
   4580             data['track'] = ','.join(track)
   4581         if locations is not None:
-> 4582             data['locations'] = ','.join(locations)
   4583         if delimited is not None:
   4584             data['delimited'] = str(delimited)

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`api.GetStreamFilter(locations=-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8)`

In the context of a function call, the primary use of a comma is to separate arguments.

Therefore, you are calling the function with four arguments: `locations=-122.75`, `36.8`, `-121.75`, and `37.8`.  This is an error, because keyword arguments must come *after* positional (i.e. regular) arguments.

If your intent was to pass a tuple, enclose it in parentheses to treat it as a single argument:

```
api.GetStreamFilter(locations=(-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8))
```

Comment: for tweet in api.GetStreamFilter(locations = ['-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8']):
    print (tweet)
    break - Worked. Thanks John.